# user privileges on remote machine using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run the following task using ansible 2.1 on a remote server (running the debian package requires sudo privileges).  However, when I run the command, it appears to fail with the error copied below.  Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this further would be greatly appreciated.

**task**

```
---
- name: transferring artifact to server 
  local_action: shell ls -d /tmp/test/target/*.jar
  register: test_build
- copy: src={{ test_build.stdout }}  dest=/home/ubuntu/ owner=ubuntu group=ubuntu mode=644 backup=yes
  become: true
  become_user: ubuntu 
  become_method: sudo
```

**error**

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user. For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ubuntu" is an unprivileged user account. You're not invoking the copy command as sudo, you're invoking "su" as sudo into an unprivileged account and running the copy command as "ubuntu" (unprivileged). Ansible is doing exactly what you tell it to.

You should not use become from an unprivileged account to get into an unprivileged account. This is a security vulnerability in Ansible. Why not login as ubuntu instead of whatever user you are using to begin with?

Comment: because I ssh into the remote server using my keypair, not the user ubuntu.  The user ubuntu is only setup on the remote server.

Comment: By default the "ubuntu" user does have root access, but you still have to invoke sudo to utilize it, which I have explained, you are not doing.

Answer (score 0):

I setup the allow_world_readable_tmpfiles flag in ansible.cfg to True (False by default in absible 2.1).  This allowed ansible to treat this as a warning and not as an error allowing me to proceed.  Other suggested options (which I did not try included using pipelining or install acl tools).